# Why the author of a post is not notified when a question is about to close?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Why is the author of a post not notified when a question is about to close? Many times I have found the question closed only when I visit the question for a probable answer barring the author to clarify his question.

Comment: Have you tried rediting the closed question? I'm pretty sure the author can still edit a closed question?

Comment: @JorgeCastro will re-editing the closed question will re-open the question

Comment: No, but you can certainly edit to mention why you don't think it's a duplicate and fix it up so that people can vote to reopen it.

Comment: Just edit it, or propose one, and then flag for moderation the question explaining what was changed and why do you think it should be re-opened. Normally a small improvement and a request from the OP to re-open a question are enough for us to take action.